# DataGridComboBox Binding with nested ReactiveList<Class> object

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I have a view model that inherits from `ReactiveObject` that contains a list of items that are displayed in a datagrid.  Each of those items contains a sub-list of items that need to be displayed in a Combobox in each row of that datagrid.  Here's what the properties in my view model looks like:

```
private ReactiveList<Material> _materials;
public ReactiveList<Material> Materials
{
    get => _materials; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _materials, value);
}
```

Here is what the `Material` class looks like:

```
public class Material
{
    public string StockCode { get; set; }
    public List<Bin> Bins { get; set; }
    public Bin SelectedBin { get; set; }
    public Material() { Bins = new List<Bin>(); }

    public class Bin
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, I have a button in my XAML that calls a reactive command that populates the `_materials` list in my view model from a SQL database (as well as the nested `Bins` property for each `Material` item)  I have `ChangeTrackingEnabled = true` on my `_materials` list that is set in the constructor of the VM (not shown).  Everything display fine in my datagrid, except the combobox that is supposed to show the `Bins` list is completely empty.  Here's an excerpt of my XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MaterialGrid" 
                  Margin="0 8 0 0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Materials}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMaterial}"
                  CanUserSortColumns="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  IsReadOnly="False"
                  Visibility="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource InvBooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                  materialDesign:DataGridAssist.CellPadding="13 8 8 8"
                  materialDesign:DataGridAssist.ColumnHeaderPadding="8"
                  Grid.Row="1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Stock Code"
                                  IsReadOnly="True"
                                  Binding="{Binding StockCode}" />
              <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Bin"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Bins, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                      SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedBin, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Bin" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I see two likely options. 1. Bins is empty. 2. Bins is set after Meterials has been added to the list. And nothing notifies the UI thats Bins is now updated. If SQL Adds to the list instead of setting a new you could try changed List<Bin> into ObservableCollection<Bin> as it notifies when changed. Not when created though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `DisplayMemberPath` property to `Name`:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Bin"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Bins}" 
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedBin, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Comment: Yikes, sorry, yes that was a typo.  It is in fact set to "Name" in my code, but the issue persists unfortunately.

Comment: If you don't see any items in the ComboBox the the Bins property returns an empty list. Please provide a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve